# Slow local windows django dev environment

Tags: windows, django, development-environment

My local django dev environment (apache 2.2, Python 2.6, Django 1.2a, mod_wsgi, sqlite, win7 64bit) is really slow. It usually takes 15sec-30sec to load a page.

Any ideas what might be slowing it down? Same application on the production server runs just fine.

Task manager shows:
[Task Manager http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/4396/20100201210438.gif](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/4396/20100201210438.gif)

Comment: Since I can't see the Windows Task Manager from here, it's hard to guess at that.  Could you tilt your screen a little so I can see what's running in the background?

Comment: How does your local box compare to your production box in terms of specs?

Comment: @S.Lott - I can't take a screenshot of my task manager now - but I doubt my machine is the problem (clean install, very low memory usage etc)

@Dominic My production box is the same. My dev is essentially a copy of my production environment.

Comment: @Franek: Until you can gather some useful data, all we have is our psychic abilities.  If one box is dramatically slower than another, logic says the copy from prod to dev isn't "essentially" the same.  You'll have to find and list the differences, or we're going to result to Tarot-card readings.

Comment: any call to remote servers from code?

Comment: @Dimitry - there is only one page with its own js that makes a remote call (from Franek's answer below)

Answer (score 7):

What host name are you using to access your site? Are you using 'localhost'? If so, try using '127.0.0.1' instead and see if it runs quicker.

Seen a few times where people would experience delays because of fact that IPV6 is enabled by default on Windows 7. This was causing issues when accessing via localhost. The solution was to edit:

```
C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

and comment out the line:

```
::1 localhost
```

Ie., make it so it reads:

```
# ::1 localhost
```

If there is a line:

```
# 127.0.0.1 localhost
```

uncomment it so it reads:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Anyway, think that was what the changes needed to be.

Comment: Graham, that didn't help. It's still very slow 80% of the time.

Comment: I had the same problem with my local Google App Engine server. Using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" did the trick. Thanks a lot!